# Github Basic oauth token not being sent with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github-api

I'm trying to send my personal access token when I'm sending the request with the ajax call, but the token is not being passed to the request. Keep seeing `API rate limit exceeded for 94.143.188.0. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit.` error. I tried doing a `beforeSend:` but that didn't work. I'm messing up somewhere, don't know where.

```
<div>
  <button id="getGithub">Github</button>
  <div id="gitResults"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="getCodewars">Codewars</button>
  <div id="cwarsResults"></div>
</div>
```

```
var getGithub = document.getElementById('getGithub');
var getCodewars = document.getElementById('getCodewars');
var gitResults = document.getElementById('gitResults');
var cwarsResults = document.getElementById('cwarsResults');
var token =  'bea978891ecb5acbfdb7c7c5cf141dd8889b6249';

getGithub.onclick = function() {
  $.getJSON({
       method: "GET",
       headers: { username: token },
       url: "https://api.github.com/users/dantesolis",
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function( returnData ) {
      console.log('This is the returnData' + returnData);
      console.log(returnData.data);
      for (var props in returnData.data) {
        console.log(returnData.data[props]);
        gitResults.innerHTML = gitResults.innerHTML + returnData.data[props]
      }
     //gitResults.innerHTML = returnData.data.avatar_url;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You may need to pass `x-oauth-basic` as the password if you're sending them using basic HTTP auth.

Comment: @kfb what do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would implement it in your case, but I'll guess something like `headers: { username: token, password: "x-oauth-basic" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after reading some more posts and searching around google I found that if I pass my token as a parameter it works. This is quite inelegant and it just circumvents the issue I'm having. Mainly not knowing how to properly set headers in an ajax request, but for those looking for an answer. I'm posting my code. If someone has a better solution, please add it.

```
<div>
  <button id="getGithub">Github</button>
  <div id="gitResults"></div>
</div>
```

```
var getGithub = document.getElementById('getGithub');
var gitResults = document.getElementById('getGithub');


getGithub.onclick = function() {
  var root =  "https://api.github.com";
  var user =  '/users/dantesolis';
  var gitHubToken = 'my_cool_token';


  $.getJSON({
      method: "GET",

        url: root+user+"?&access_token="+gitHubToken,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log('This is the returnData' + response);   

          var link = document.createElement('a');
          var p1 = document.createElement('p');
          var p2 = document.createElement('p');

          link.href = response.html_url; 
          link.innerHTML = '@dantesolis';
          p1.innerHTML = response.followers;
          p2.innerHTML = response.following;
          gitResults.appendChild(link);
          gitResults.appendChild(p1);
          gitResults.appendChild(p2);
        }, /* End of success */
       error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
         console.log('Error');
         console.log(xhr.status);
       }
    })
}
```